# int variable:3;

Tags: c, struct

In C I saw this code:

```
struct stud{
int b:3;
};
```

This was compiling in gcc.
What do variables `b` and `3` represent? Also, please explain the use of `:`.

Are there anymore signs like this?

Comment: Bit field of a structure.

Comment: you might refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105403/size-of-c-structure

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does 'unsigned temp:3' means](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950029/what-does-unsigned-temp3-means)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that `b` uses 3 bits of the int. The term is "bit field".

Usually this is combined with other variables using other bits of the same or other ints.

The idea is to either pack values harder to save space, or more common to match the data from some hardware device.

Comment: how is the memory for Bit fields organized. The bit fields types share bytes, right?

Comment: It is pretty much up to the implementation, but if you have two 3-bit fields they are supposed to share a byte.